# Matrix with words

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\rule[0.5\dimexpr-#1+1.2ex]{0pt}{#1}\hfil$}p{#1}    <{$\hfil}@{}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
    \Huge
    $\begin{array}{|C{2.5cm} | C{2.5cm} |C{2.5cm} |}\hline
    hello & hello & hello\\\hline
    hello & hello & hello\\\hline
    hello & hello & hello\\\hline
    \end{array} $
\end{center}     

\end{document}
```

Produce that:

[image]

Regrettably, with my code I can't do my objective.
I want a more big matrix, where  in each square I have a title, and below, text. All with maximum width, for the text. Also, text outside the square.

Something like this:

[image]

Can you help me?
Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

to your table i add one more column and row. for them i defined new commands: `mct` for text above "table" and `mcl` for the text left of "table":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mct[2]{\multicolumn{1}{@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1} @{} }{#2}}
\newcommand\mcl[2]{\multicolumn{1}{ >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \large
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}|
                *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|}}
\mct{2.5cm}{}
    &   \mct{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}
        &   \mct{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}
            &   \mct{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}  \\
    \cline{2-4}
\mcl{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}
    &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
        hello hello hello
        &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
            hello hello hello
            &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
                hello hello hello               \\
    \cline{2-4}
\mcl{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}
    &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
        hello hello hello
        &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
            hello hello hello
            &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
                hello hello hello               \\
    \cline{2-4}
\mcl{2.5cm}{hello hello hello}
    &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
        hello hello hello
        &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
            hello hello hello
            &   \textbf{\Large HELLO}\newline
                hello hello hello               \\
    \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Zarko, how can I do for transform the code into a image? I try changed `\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}` in instead of `\documentclass{article}` but it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @Vidal, remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`. also you not need option `tikz`.

Comment: When I did it, remain  a bit of space left... Is possible remove it?

Comment: you declare 2mm border around the table :-), reduce it to for example 0.25mm. white space on the left side is caused width column width. you can reduce it in accordance to text in this cells

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative which gives you arguably more control and is shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{m-node/.style={text
width=1.8cm,font=\sffamily,align=center,inner sep=6pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix (hello) [matrix of nodes,nodes={m-node,draw},node distance=-\pgflinewidth] {
      {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} 
       & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} \\
      {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello}
       & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} \\
      {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} 
       & {{\Large Hello}\\ Hello Hello Hello Hello} \\
    };
  \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
  {\node[m-node,above=2mm of hello-1-\X]{hello hello hello};
  \node[m-node,left=2mm of hello-\X-1]{HELLO HELLO};}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]